# Vuetify v-data-table override itemsPerPageOptions when using the options.sync prop

Tags: vuetify.js

I am using the :options.sync prop on my v-data-table in to fetch paginated data server side. However, the default itemsPerPage options are 5,10,15 & ALL.

I tried changing the options using :items-per-page-options using a property inside my data object itemsPerPageOptions:[50,100,250,-1] but it is still showing the old values. The way I am trying worked before I was using the "new" :options prop, but with it in place its not doing it. From the documentation itself, the options prop has no key value pair for items-per-page-options.

```
<v-data-table
          :server-items-length="totalTrades"
          :options.sync="options"
          :footer-props="{ 'items-per-page options': itemsPerPageOptions }"
          :loading="loading"
          :items="items"
          :headers="headers"
          class="transparent"
          dense
          fixed-header
          height="800"
          item-key="id"
        ></v-data-table>


 data: () => ({
    options: {},
    itemsPerPageOptions: [50, 100, 250, -1],
    totalTrades: -1,
    search: "",
    searchForWallet: "",
    
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are providing wrong value for `footer-props` - you should use **camelCase** rather than **kebab-case**:

```html
<template>
  <v-data-table :items="items" :headers="headers" :options.sync="pagination" :footer-props="footerOptions" />
</template>

<script>
export default
{
  name: 'MyComponent',
  data()
  {
    return {
      pagination:
        {
          page: 1,
          itemsPerPage: 50,
          sortBy: ['product_name'],
          sortDesc: [false],
        },
      footerOptions:
        {
          itemsPerPageOptions: [25, 50, 100], // this is the proper name - not "items-per-page options" like what you're using
        }       
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `props-items-per-page-options` does work as the [documentation explains](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-items-per-page-options).

[image]

Here a code sample in Composition API style

```
const footerOptions = [
  { value: 5, title: '5' },
  { value: 10, title: '10' },
  { value: 25, title: '25' },
  { value: 50, title: '50' },
  { value: -1, title: '$vuetify.dataFooter.itemsPerPageAll' }
]
```

And then the usage in the template

```
<template>
  <v-data-table-server v-model:items-per-page="itemsPerPage" :items-per-page-options="footerOptions" :headers="headers" :items-length="totalItems"
```

Eventually, it will render like below

[image]

Please note that the option of displaying 5 items per page is available, unlike the default settings.